# Unable to Pair to Mac with Visual Studio 2022 17.3 - .NET MAUI

Tags: .net-6.0, .net-maui

I'm trying to pair with my Mac to build the iOS version of a MAUI application. I'm running VS2022 17.3 on both PC and Mac but getting this:
[image]
Kind of stumped as to why on a brand new Windows install and fresh versions of VS this basic function doesn't work.

Anyone know what to do to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

**The reason this was not working was that the OP did not have Mono installed on their System.**

**OG answer:**

So I just tried it out on the following versions of VS MAC 17.3(Build 2102) with VS Windows 17.3 and it seems to be working

Steps I recommend you took to make sure this worked for you as well:

- Make sure both PC are on the same network(LAN/WIFI)
- Make sure there are no updates left over at your end.
- If this was connected on a previous version of VS then you might have to disconnect/delete and reconnect this device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. It's a fresh install of windows with newly installed VS and I've not turned the Mac since 5 years ago. Was definitely never paired with this PC. All updates are applied and I can VNC to the Mac. Not sure what else to look at. Thanks again

Comment: XCode was listing no updates, although I ran it after installing the latest OS and it did install some components. But when trying again it made no difference.

Comment: Can you share your MAC config, if your mac has been off for 5 years maybe you don't have the right configuration, Also can you confirm if your MAC is able to debug

Comment: I updated to Monterey, ran XCode to get the latest content installed, removed Visual Studio 2017 following the guide provided by MS. I've now installed Visual Studio 2022 17.4 Preview 1 (as suggested by someone on the docs.Microsoft.com questions and answers system and I get this IDB issue. When you "Mac Config", which configuration spoecifically are you askign for? And how do I check if the Mac and debug?

Comment: So I've had further problems with this debacle. Why don't any articles about setting up Pair To Mac mention that you have to install Mono on the Mac first? I found in some obscure message someone answered on a QA site that they installed Mono and it resolved their issue. Same in my case.

Comment: Well that's actually mentioned if I am not wrong https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/. "If you would prefer not to install Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio 2019 can automatically configure the Mac build host with Xamarin.iOS and Mono. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#mono

Comment: As I read it, it says that the windows end will automatically install mono on the Mac. BUT I had to do it manually, the WIndows side wouldn't initiate it, But at any rate I installed VS for Mac, so it should have done it anyway. "If you would prefer not to install Visual Studio for Mac" ... I didn't prefer not to, I actually did it. But, that page does not say you have to download the Mono for Mac installer and do it manually.

Comment: @StephenYork That's interesting! i think this will interest you https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-maui-xcode14/

Comment: This answer is incorrect. OP's VS is already connected (paired) successfully to the MAC. The error shown is in starting the IDB agent.